# How to make a constant binary number adapt to a Generic statement in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, quartus

As you can see, I am trying to make a generic component that tests if a number is equals to one (using WHEN ELSE for that).

```vhd
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

ENTITY isone IS
GENERIC ( N: integer );
PORT (a : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
      equals : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END isone;

ARCHITECTURE rtl OF isone IS
BEGIN
    equals <= '1' WHEN A = "0001" ELSE '0';
END rtl;
```

My problem is, how do I adapt the `"0001"` in `equals <= '1' WHEN A = "0001" ELSE '0';` to extend its size when, for example, the Generic N value is 8?

Only solution that I thought of was changing the `"0001"` for a `a-a +'1'` (pretty bad one)

Comment: `equals <= '1' WHEN unsigned(A) = 1 ELSE '0';`  might work

Comment: Using package numeric_std and a type conversion  when unsigned (A) = 1 , or without the type conversion in -2008 using package numeric_std_unsigned. Both guaranteed to use numerical equality.

Comment: In package numeric_std for the operator overload "="[unsigned, natural return boolean] the natural parameter is converted using to_integer with the size (length) of the other parameter.

Comment: In general you should use ieee.numeric_std.all instead of ieee.std_logic_unsigned, which is an old solution and is not a standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the conversion functions of the standard package "numeric_std":

```vhdl
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY isone IS
    GENERIC ( N: integer );
    PORT (a : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
          equals : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END isone;

ARCHITECTURE rtl OF isone IS
    CONSTANT ONE : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0) := STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(1, N));
BEGIN
    equals <= '1' WHEN A = one ELSE '0';
END rtl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, ieee.numeric_std defines the function:

`function "=" (L: UNSIGNED; R: NATURAL) return BOOLEAN;`

So you could just do
`equals <= '1' WHEN UNSIGNED(A) = 1 ELSE '0';`

Or better, start with unsigned

```vhdl
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY isone IS
GENERIC ( N: integer );
PORT (a : IN UNSIGNED(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
      equals : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END isone;

ARCHITECTURE rtl OF isone IS
BEGIN
    equals <= '1' WHEN a = 1 ELSE '0';
END rtl;
```

BUT! if this is the only entity here and you are sure you want to use unsigned arithmetic for std_logic_Vector input, you can use VHDL-2008's `ieee.numeric_std_unsigned`:

```vhdl
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;

ENTITY isone IS
GENERIC ( N: integer );
PORT (a : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
      equals : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END isone;

ARCHITECTURE rtl OF isone IS
BEGIN
    equals <= '1' WHEN a = 1 ELSE '0';
END rtl;
```